# Ubuntu 16.04 /etc/network/interfaces vs GUI locations

Tags: ubuntu, networking, headless

I can edit /etc/network/interfaces on Ubuntu 16.04 to manually set IP information. I can also use the lightdm/unity/GUI to set it via the "Network" application.

I started with a headed/GUI build and set my network information. Now I am headless with `systemctl disable lightdm`.

I need to make network changes, but noticed that my (working at the moment) GUI modifications to the network (e.g. Static IP) aren't saved here.

**Question**

1. Where does the GUI "Network" application store its network information?

Comment: The GUI is just an interface. The question is, to what? I guess NetworkManager is used in Ubuntu? In that case, check `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` (I can post a full answer if you confirm it).

Comment: You're correct. Its under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<connectionname>`.....how does the system know to pull from there vs `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu GUI tools uses the NetworkManager by default. [The connection information is stored in files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html#KEYFILE_SECTION), each file representing a connection.

`/etc/network/interfaces` can also be used for [network interfaces configuration](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html). If you manually configure an interface here, [NetworkManager will stop managing it](https://askubuntu.com/a/431693).